# Error: connect ECONNREFUSED into node.js when i am start my .js server file

Tags: node.js, apache, php-7.2

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED Ip address:3306
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1106:14)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (/App Directory Pat /node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:144:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (/**App Directory Path**/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:51:23)
    at Connection.connect (/**App Directory Path**/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:119:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/app/videostatus/app.js:17:12)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:829:12)
```

This is my node.js code

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello World!');
}).listen(3006);

var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
 host: '',
  user: '',
  password: '',
  database: ''
});

connection.connect((err) => {
    if (err) {
        return console.error(err);
    }
});
connection.query('SELECT * FROM category_master where category_isactive = 1 ORDER BY `order` ASC', function (error, results, fields) {
  if (error) throw error;
  console.log('The solution is: ', results[0].solution);
});

connection.end();
```

Please help me i have spend 2 days but not found anything.
Thank you.

Comment: Please paste the `.js` code

Comment: I have added .js code.

Comment: where is you MySQL db? on which port? can you access it via telnet?

Comment: Your mysql is either not up, or you are not specifying correct ip + creds. For your local mysql, host needs to be `host: '127.0.0.1'`

Answer (score 1):

Your MySQL server is not appearing to be running.

If you're sure it's running, then you're using the wrong `host` in your `mysql.createConnection()`. You should use `127.0.0.1`, but you may also try `localhost` or `::1`. (IPv6 equivalent of `127.0.0.1`).

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you have to look at the port number or checking the entire database connection credentials.

**I fixed that bug with the port number, which wasn't matched before.**

Answer (score 0):

Please Check your internet connection if you are providing an **IP** inside DB Host attribute :

Like :

```
"database":
             {
              "host":"119.18.55.154"
             }
```

Answer (score 0):

I used local ip '127.0.0.1' instead of 'localhost' it is working for me.
My config.

```
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    user: 'root',
    password: '',
    database: 'test', 
});
connection.connect((err) => {
    if(err){
        throw err;
    }
    console.log("---MYSQL CONNECTED---");
});
```